# First value returns "undefined" when parsed with the following

Tags: javascript, json, object, multidimensional-array, for-loop

When I parse this object with the function below, the first value that I get in the table is "undefined". Any idea as to why this could be happening? Am I parsing incorrectly? Should I be using a different loop?

```
var students = [
{
    fn : "Stone",
    ln : "Carpenter",
    scores : [61,99,73,68,80,62,176,78]
},
{
    fn : "Samson",
    ln : "Sears",
    scores : [68,193,91,190,95,65,171,75]
},
{
    fn : "Quin",
    ln : "Morton",
    scores : [79,95,161,92,182,163,198,182]
},
{
fn : "Qunitessa",
        ln : "Hardy",
    scores : [99,65,75,69,77,67,86,78]
},
{
    fn : "Ashley",
    ln : "England",
    scores : [147,70,81,64,148,71,70,63]
},
{
    fn : "Thaddeus",
    ln : "Hutchinson",
    scores : [99,190,188,185,160,88,89,76]
},
{
    fn : "Yeo",
    ln : "Hayes",
    scores : [88,64,199,165,198,76,74,81]
},
{
    fn : "Rylee",
    ln : "Larson",
    scores : [71,126,63,71,168,173,175,88]
}
];

function updateTable(obj) {
var rows, 
len;

len = obj.length;

rows = "<table>"
rows += "<tbody>"


for (var i in obj) {

var scoreLen,
score,
sum;

scoreLen = obj[i].scores.length;
scores = obj[i].scores;

rows += "<tr>"
rows += "<td>" + obj[i].fn + "</td>"
rows += "<td>" + obj[i].ln + "</td>"

    for(j=0; j<scoreLen; j+=1) {
        rows += "<td>" + scores[j] + "</td>"
    }

rows += "<td>" + arraySum(obj[i].scores) + "</td>"
rows += "</tr>"

}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = rows
console.log(rows)
}
```

Comment: Here's a [rewrite of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/C38ny/) using DOM methods for element creation instead of string concatenation and `innerHTML`.

Comment: I am asssuming string concatenation and innnerHTML are bad? :)

Comment: I have a strong personal bias in favor of using DOM methods when working in a DOM. In my view, markup belongs on the server. Once the markup has arrived and been rendered into a DOM, one should interact with it as a DOM. That's not to say that there isn't place for some de-normalization using `innerHTML`, but I personally prefer to keep it to a minimum. *(Again, this is my personal bias.)*

Comment: I see that I used `i` instead of `j` to grab the score. You probably caught that, but [here's the corrected version](http://jsfiddle.net/C38ny/1/).

Answer (score 2):

This will iterate over properties of the array other than the array elements like `length`. You should iterate using a for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the correct implementation of `updateTable` function. `students` is an array of objects, but you are trying to access it as an object of objects. That is why it is undefined.

```
var students = [{obj1:stuff}, {obj2:stuff}, ... ,{objn:stuff}]
```

`students[0] returns {obj1:stuff}, students[1] returns {obj2:stuff}` and so on.

```
function updateTable(arr) {
var rows, 
len;

len = arr.length;

rows = "<table>"
rows += "<tbody>"


for (var i =0; i< len; i++) {

var scoreLen,
score,
sum;

scoreLen = arr[i].scores.length;
scores = arr[i].scores;

rows += "<tr>"
rows += "<td>" + arr[i].fn + "</td>"
rows += "<td>" + arr[i].ln + "</td>"

    for(j=0; j<scoreLen; j+=1) {
        rows += "<td>" + scores[j] + "</td>"
    }

rows += "<td>" + arraySum(arr[i].scores) + "</td>"
rows += "</tr>"

}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = rows
console.log(rows)
}
```

Comment: this function isn't working for me. its gets stuck here "rows += "<td>" + arr[i].fn + "</td>"

Comment: apologies, not sure what I did prior, but you function does indeed work. :)

Answer (score 0):

When iterating over items in an array, never use `for .. in`. Instead, always use a numerical loop, such as:

```
for (var i=0, len=myArray.length; i<len; ++i){ … }
```

Or if you want to iterate from back to front with less typing:

```
for (var i=myArray.length;i--;){ … }
```